# Checkbox search php

Tags: php, mysql, search, checkbox

I have made a list of company include their fields and sizes. I made a few check boxes in order to filter them out

```
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="field[]" value="Water">Water </td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="Small">Small </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="field[]" value="Energy">Energy </td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="Medium">Medium </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="field[]" value="Wind">Wind </td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="Big">Big </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="field[]" value="Earth">Earth </td>
```

And here 's the PHP checkbox search:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{               

    //if( count($_POST['field']) > 0)
    if (isset($_POST['field']))
    {       
        $field =  implode(',',$_POST['field']);
        $str = "AND company_field LIKE '$field'";
    }
    else
    {
        $str = "";
    }

    //if( count($_POST['size']) > 0 )
    if (isset($_POST['size']))
    {           
        $size =  implode(',',$_POST['size']);
        $str1 = "AND company_size LIKE '$size'";
    }
    else
    {
        $str1 = "";
    }
    $run = "SELECT * FROM company WHERE 1=1 ".$str.$str1;
    $reslt = mysql_query($run);
```

The checkbox work fine if I didn't select any or select one of each column. 
But when I select 2 or more in 1 column, the query will be like this:
`SELECT * FROM company_info WHERE 1=1 AND company_size LIKE 'M, B'` and I know that this query is wrong, it should be 
`WHERE 1=1 AND company_size LIKE 'M' OR company_size LIKE 'B'`.
So I'm looking for solution or code for this.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ,

$field =  implode(',',$_POST['field']);
$str = "AND `company_field` IN ( ".$field." )";

Comment: I have tried it but the query is like this:
"SELECT * FROM company_info WHERE 1=1 AND company_size LIKE ('M, B')" and it won't work because it 's suppoed to be like this "SELECT * FROM company_info WHERE 1=1 AND company_size LIKE ('M', 'B')" with each element covered in quote

Comment: go for this, 

$field = "'".implode("','", $_POST['field'])."'"

$str = "AND company_field IN ( ".$field." )";

Answer (score 0):

Simply Try This

```
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{               
    $str = NULL;
    //if( count($_POST['field']) > 0)
    if (isset($_POST['field']))
    {       
        $field  = implode(',',$_POST['field']);
        $str  =" AND company_field IN ($field) ";
    }

    //if( count($_POST['size']) > 0 )
    if (isset($_POST['size']))
    {           
        $size =  implode(',',$_POST['size']);
        $str  .= " AND company_size IN ($size) ";
    }

    $run = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company WHERE ".$str);



?>
```

Comment: Thanks but when I tried, it happened the same problem as above comment for last answer.

Comment: Remove 1=1  and try now

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got solved by the above. I appreciate it.